# PPO Parameter Tuning

Tags: tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I have tested PPO-Clip in my own environment. However, after achieving converge, the learning curve will dump into a low enough reward at times like the the following.
[image]
When I check the training log, I find the value loss will suddenly increase during the abnormal issue like the following list.
[image]
If anyone know how to solve this issue, I will appreciate it.